# I need help matching to data points

Tags: indexing, match

I have a workbook, on sheet 1 column F row 2 is my data DAL (its a city abv) and I need to check it against sheets 3 column F, the whole column there may be DAL in the sheets 3 Column F multi times or none at all, I need to tell me if it sees a match. So if it finds DAL in sheets 3 column F it will say YES and if not NO.

Answer (score 0):

You may use [`MATCH`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/MATCH-function-e8dffd45-c762-47d6-bf89-533f4a37673a) with [`IFERROR`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IFERROR-function-c526fd07-caeb-47b8-8bb6-63f3e417f611) to check if an item has been found or not:

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(F2,Sheet3!F:F, 0)), "Not found", "Yes, found")
```

See the screen below:

[image] **=>** [image]